# How to call my ViewController in applogic pod library in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please let me know how to call my ViewController in Applogic pod library. I have already searched a lot, but didn't get any result.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NewUserNearByViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController  *loginViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
// If Login View Controller is not a Navigation Controller then you need to create Navigation Controller

[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:true];
```

Comment: Post code that you have tried

Comment: Why do you want to call your VC in a pod lib? I am not aware of ApplogicPodlib but do you mind providing us with a little information on what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can speak your native language with me if you feel uncomfortable in English (I'll edit it in your question and delete comments)

Comment: As in android, we are using forName to call my activity. In objective C, Is it possible to call my controller ?  I attached android calling method.                  
     i = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this,Class.forName("com.svg.chatsrun.Activity.Voice_Call"));
                startActivity(i);

Comment: i want to call my controller from POD file Controller because i am unable to import my controller in POD File Controller .so  how can i achive this . Thanks

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are not familiar with technical lexicon of iOS which is why you are having issues communicating your problem to us. I am not Android Dev so can't understand your analogy there. From what I understood, you want to access one viewController X in another viewController Y? If yes, why? Do you want to access data of VC X in Y? Or do you just want to navigate from X to Y? Also, you might wanna ping me when you respond (Type @ and my name, and I will be notified of your response)

Comment: yes i want to navigate from POD File .

Comment: What do you mean by a POD file? Do you mean Cocoapods pod? You should never try to modify behaviour of the Pods. I can't imagine a scenario in which you might have to do that. It looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, I'd suggest reading the basics on iOS dev and Cocoapods so that you could explain yourself in a clearer way. Which pod are you using anyways? Does it have a navigation controller?

Comment: i am using thired party POD file "pod 'Applozic','~> 5.8.0'" . i am talking about this one .

Comment: Your particular pod is an isolated dependency, you shouldn't call your local classes from this pod library. If you want to do so, you have to fork this library instead of using cocoa pods. If you will change pod library, then after next update all these changes will gone